# Phonegap 3.0 and newer - Is there a Plugin to Update the App Badge without a Push Notification?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, badge

I am trying to update the badge for a Phonegap 3.1 iOS application.

---

**What Has Worked Before**
To achieve this in older versions of Phonegap/Cordova, I used the following plugin:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/Badge

**Why that no longer works**
Plugins in Phonegap 3.0+ are now installed via the command line.
I'm under the impression that the plugin above (which has a "last updated" time of over a year ago) is not compliant with the new plugin install process.

**What I've Thought to Try So Far**
I thought to try and run `phonegap local plugin add https://<path to the git repo>` just incase the plugin still worked with 3.0+, but I can't seem to find the address of the actual repo.

I was hoping the [Phonegap 3.0 documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification) would have an example of setting the badge, but I don't see anything along those lines.

---

**Does anyone know of a Phonegap3.0+ plugin to manually set of the badge number for an iOS app?**

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge

```
window.plugin.notification.badge.clear();
window.plugin.notification.badge.set(0);  // alternative
```

Pretty simpel. Can also be installed via **CLI**.

Comment: have you used this plugin to work in the background while the application is minimized? I'm using it in an application to update the badge every 5 minutes but it's updating the badge only when you're inside the application.

I used another plugin to allow background tasking, which seems to be working, but once the time runs out when the application is on the background the badge doesn't refresh.

Comment: I used it every time a notification in my application fired, it would update the badge like I wanted it to, also when the app was in the background. (After all isn't that the primary use and intention of the plugin?)
However, I used Cordova 3.0, I am not sure if it still works properly with Cordova 3.4. I am having some issues with the 3.4 Version regarding other plugins.

Comment: yes I've heard the 3.4 is giving issues to some people, I'm using the 3.3 version atm. Could you make the updates without any other plugins in the background? I should check that out